# Assign text in "Text View" to a variable makes app crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uitextview

basically when the code below runs, the app crashes and I can't figure out why. I think I may be assigning the text inside of "test1" to the variable "new1var" in the wrong way, but I'm not sure.

```
@IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField! //text field
@IBOutlet weak var test1: UITextView! //text view


@IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) { //when a button is pressed

    let newvar = test.text
    let new1wvar = test1.text     //this line is where it crashes
}
```

Thank you so much for your help (I'm new to swift)!

Comment: And what does crash log says?

Comment: is test1 wired up properly as an IBOutlet?

Comment: i think you have renamed your outlet after connecting

Comment: Probably your textfields have multiple IBOutlets that's why it is crashing. Remove all outlets of your textfields by just right click and check for referencing outlets. Remove all of them and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

App crash because `test1.text` maybe `nil`. `UITextView`'s text or `UITextField`'s text is nil at the first time it's initialized.

To resolve this problem:

Replace this line

```
let new1wvar = test1.text
```

by:

```
let new1wvar = test1.text ?? "" // If test1.text is nil, then will use "" to asign
```

Comment: That doesn't prevent the code from crashing if `test1` is `nil`

Comment: I assum test1 is wired up properly as an IBOutlet :D

Comment: I guess the issue is that the IBOutlet is **not** connected.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
@IBOutlet weak var test1: UITextView!
```

says that `test1` is an implicitly unwrapped optional. So compiler would allow you to access it without unwrapping it but its your responsibility to make sure that before accessing it, its not nil.

Make sure that you have properly linked `test1` to your Storyboard/XIB.

After making sure that it is linked properly in other answer give some default value if `test1.text` is nil.

```
let new1wvar = test1.text ?? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var test1: UITextField!


@IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
     guard let  newvar = test.text ,let new1wvar = test1.text else{
        print("Error")
        return
     }
     print(newvar)
     print(new1wvar)
}
```